# How do I extract out the common xhr promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest

So i have a couple of methods which are supposed to return a promise.
These methods are like promisified XHR, so I was trying out to extract the common promise XHR part out, but I am unable to.

I have tried a couple of things. For example:

```
function sendXHR(reqMethod, reqUrl, successFn, errorFn) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                try {
                    resolve(successFn(xmlhttp));
                }
                catch(ex){
                    reject(errorFn(ex));
                }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open(reqMthod, reqUrl, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    });
```

```
function returnXHRPromise(url) { 
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   sendXHR('GET', url, function (xmlhttp) { ... some code ...
    resolve(...) }, function (ex) { ... some code ... 
    reject(...) }
 })
}
```

Tried this as well

```
function returnXHRPromise(url) { 
   sendXHR('GET', url, function (xmlhttp) { ... some code ...
    resolve(...) }, function (ex) { ... some code ... 
    reject(...) }
}
```

Earlier it was something like -

```
function returnXHRPromise(url) { 
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                try {
                   ... some code ... ; resolve(...)

                }
                catch(ex){
                    ...some code ... ; reject(...);
                }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
   }
 })
}
```

Need to seperate the promisified XHR part and the main working of the function.

Comment: for a start, I'd use load/error XHR events ... besides that, what part of the first code is the problem?

Comment: Do you mean xhr.onload and xhr.onerror? The code doesn't work

Comment: xhr.onload/onerror (or xhr.addEventListener('load' | 'error' ... does work everywhere, except old internet exploder ... are you using OLD IE?

Comment: No need to support IE. Anyways, how will this solve my problem? My problem is somewhat like having couple of methods (expected to return a promise) and to extract the common parts of those methods. In this case, it's XHR.

Comment: Not sure why your first code fails to do what you want, can you describe the problem with that code, i.e. why it's not doing what you want? *perhaps you should add the event listeners after .open and before .send* - that's how I've always done it, and it never fails

Comment: anyway, here's how I'd do it - https://pastebin.com/DakLzvYy

Comment: Thanks for the code. But can you make sendXHR() return a promise?

Comment: it does return a promise, `return new Promise....` see?

Comment: No, I mean, the place where you are making the sendXHR() function call, can you put that inside inside another function (let's say returnXHR), which returns a promise?

Comment: yes, that will return the promise if you return sendXHR().... that's how return works